# MockMvc response returns 404, expected response 201

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I am new to unit testing REST API in Spring Boot.

I am expecting response status as CREATED but instead I am getting a PAGE NOT FOUND error.

Below is the code for:-

**UserControllerUnitTests**

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { CommonConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class UserControllerUnitTests {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper;
    private static final String URI = "/users";

    MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext webAppContext;

    @Mock
    UserService userService;

    MvcResult mvcResult;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void initialize() throws Exception {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webAppContext).build();
    ....
    ....
    ....
   
    void shouldReturnStatusCreatedIfValidUserPassedForPostUser(long index) throws Exception {
        int expectedStatus = HttpStatus.CREATED.value();
        UserDAO returnUser;
    
        UserDAO user = userList.get(index);
        userList.remove(index);
        String jsonContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
    
        user.setId(index);
        user.setEncryptedPassword(null);
    
        Mockito.when(userService.addUser(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(user);
    
        mvcResult = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(URI)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(jsonContent)).andReturn();
    
        //Mockito.verify(userService, Mockito.times(1)).addUser(Mockito.any());
    
        int actualStatus = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        Assert.assertEquals("Response status should be CREATED", expectedStatus, actualStatus);
    
        jsonContent = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        returnUser = mapper.readValue(jsonContent, UserDAO.class);
    
        Assert.assertEquals("EncryptedPassword should not be returned", null, 
                                          returnUser.getEncryptedPassword());
    }
```

**User Controller.class**

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("users/")
 public class UserController {

     UserService userService;
    
     @Autowired
     public UserController(UserService userService) {
         this.userService = userService;
     }
     ....
     ....
     ....

     @PostMapping(path = "",
            consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }, 
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public ResponseEntity<UserDAO> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDAO user) {
        String password = user.getEncryptedPassword();
        user.setEncryptedPassword(null);
        UserDAO retreivedUser;
    
        if(user.getId() != 0)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    
        user.setEncryptedPassword(password);
        retreivedUser = userService.addUser(user);
        if(retreivedUser != null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(retreivedUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

The full code can be found at https://github.com/vineethmaller/springboot-userservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spotted a few errors:

1. Get rid of ContextConfiguration

   ```java
   @SpringBootTest
   // @ContextConfiguration(classes = { CommonConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class})
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   class UserControllerUnitTests {
   ```
2. Specify correct mapping on the controller (no slash)

   ```java
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("users")
   public class UserController {
   ```
3. You setup your UserService mock which is not used in the test. Did you mean @MockBean?

   ```java
   @MockBean
   UserService userService;
   ```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I also included a bootstrap.yml properties file to test/resources to disable Spring cloud bus.